# 2C# loading a form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a main Form with an event to open another Form.

Inside the first Form I define the event like this:

```
private void softToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _frmSetting = new frmSetting();
        _frmSetting.ShowDialog();
    }
```

The event open a Form in the Dialog box. Everything is ok.

Inside the Form2 before the *InitializeComponent();*, I want to change the content of a TextBox on the Form 2.

So I do this `this.textBox1.Text = "New text";` but it didn't work then I output to console:

```
this.textBox1.Text = "New text";
System.Console.WriteLine(this.textBox1.Text);
```

But this takes effect when immediately when the Form1 starts..I can see the console output.
Normally the Console output were supposed to ve viewed only when I call Form2.

Does someone understand my needs?

EDIT

```
public form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            try
            {
            this.txtServer = new TextBox();
            //this._parameter = new Parameter();

            //this._get_parameter = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            String _server_name;
            //this._parameter.get_db_connection_parameters().TryGetValue("server", out _server_name);
            this.txtServer.Text = _server_name.ToString();

            System.Console.WriteLine(txtServer.Text + "---");
        }
        catch (Exception er) { System.Console.WriteLine("An error occurs :" + er.Message + " - " + er.StackTrace); }
    }
```

Please don't bother about the commented lines, it works _server_name variable is getting its value from a text file and it works at this stage. The problem is around this line:

```
this.txtServer.Text = _server_name.ToString();
```

Comment: would you clarify the problem ? do you want to initialize a textbox in form 2 with a specific text, so that when form2 show the textbox has a text of "New text"??

Comment: You have to set any values *after* `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: You need to show where you are setting the text box value.  Are you doing it before or after calling `ShowDialog`?

Comment: yes I change it like that @Allon but nothing happen,, still the same

Comment: yes @Sara, that's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: @Steven, I am setting the textbox in the Form2() constructor so that the textbox loads when the Form2 is loading tow

Comment: Then you'll have to show us a bit more of your code. Where and how you change it, etc.

Comment: Did you do it before or after the the call to `InitializeComponent`?

Comment: It should work after InitializeComponent(); regarding that you created the textbox in design time.But they easiest way to see what changed the text is to set a break point in the TextChanged event of this textbox and trace who changed the text after settings it to "New Text" in this case note that you should set your dersired text after InitializeComponent

Comment: this.txtServer = new TextBox(); creates a new Textobx so you should set its location otherwise do not recreate it and just set its text

Comment: I just edited it with the Form2 code

Comment: You are creating a dynamic Textbox but not adding it to the controls collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to all,
everything works fine now. In fact, I was initialising Form2 in Form1() constructor and was getting this error Object reference to non object initialising (something like that).
I move it here:

```
private void softToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _frmSetting = new frmSetting();
    _frmSetting.ShowDialog();
}
```

and now inside the Form2() after `initializeComponent()`
I just do this

```
this.txtServer = _server_name;
```

and it works

Answer (score 3):

You're overcomplicating this.  First, as others have said, you can't do it before the call to `InitializeComponent`.  Also, you don't need to create a new text box after the call to `InitializeComponent`.  Once that method has been called, the `txtServer` text box will already be created and properly initialized.  All you need to do then is set the value of its `Text` property:

```
public form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    try
    {
        String _server_name;
        // set value of _server_name
        txtServer.Text = _server_name;
    }
    catch (Exception er) { System.Console.WriteLine("An error occurs :" + er.Message + " - " + er.StackTrace); }
}
```

Comment: upvoted for beating me to it and using the word "overcomplicating" !

Answer (score 0):

You can't set any values to textbox before `initializeComponent();`. If you look into initializeComponent function, you will see, that it does initialize all controls added in designer and your textbox as well.

You **can't** set the TextBox.Text property before initialisation, it will fail, that's it.